# tomcat fails when the number of dependencies in pom.xml reaches a certain threshold

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I have this project that uses spring-boot. In Intellij it works just fine, but when I run it using "mvn spring-boot:run", tomcat won't start properly ("A child container failed during start").

I tried to use the pom.xml file for a test program (a much smaller one), and the same thing happened, tomcat doesn't start. I started to comment out dependencies, and all of a sudden it worked. I noticed after a while that it didn't matter what dependency I commented out (if the code didn't use any of its components), but it was the number of dependencies used that mattered.

Is it supposed to be like this?

[Update 1]

I get the following exceptions (stack trace removed):

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
>
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
>
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start embedded container; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException:
>   Unable to start embedded Tomcat

[Update 2]
I did also check total/max/free memory using the Runtime class, and the values are almost the same with Intellij and "mvn spring-boot:run".

Comment: depending on the number of dependencies you have, you might just need to start tomcat with more memory. But why do you have dependencies that your code doesn't even use?

Comment: Do you have any exception in your logs ?

Comment: XtremeBaumer: The other 'test' project doesn't use them, but the solution we're developing is. So is there some default value for the memory allocated to tomcat that is different depending on how you run the program (in my case Intellij or maven) ?

Comment: Stack trace removed - why?